# Cant find uploaded build in saucelabs dashboard which was uploaded through Circleci

Tags: android, circleci, saucelabs

I am using Circleci for CI and saucelabs for automated testing. The script I am using to upload apk to saucelabs through circleci is executing successfully and I am getting a build success in circleci but I can't find the uploaded build in saucelabs dashboard. Below is the script I am using it. Any leads will be highly appreciated.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

curl -u sreed****:7868155f-d7f1-****-8ff2-4df37c2**** -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/octet-stream" https://saucelabs.com/rest/v1/storage/sree*****/app-debug.apk?overwrite=true --data-binary app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have @ sign missing before the path to the file. Please refer the instructions here: https://wiki.saucelabs.com/display/DOCS/Uploading+Mobile+Applications+to+Sauce+Storage+for+Testing

Your code should be like this:

```
curl -u sreed****:7868155f-d7f1-****-8ff2-4df37c2**** -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/octet-stream" https://saucelabs.com/rest/v1/storage/sree*****/app-debug.apk?overwrite=true --data-binary @app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk
```